# Extracting embedded hyperlinks from PDF file

Tags: r, pdf

I am currently working with PDF files in R. Specifically, I need to collect information related with hyperlinks embedded in the text of the PDF file. What I have done so far was parsing the PDF file using the `pdftools` package. Yet, it renders only the text but not the underlying hyperlinks. Below you can find an example of a PDF file with two embedded hyperlinks (the words "sentencia" and "aqui") and the code I have used.

```
library(dplyr)
txt <- pdftools::pdf_text(pdf = "http://www.corteidh.or.cr/docs/comunicados/cp_47_17.pdf") %>%
    paste(., collapse = "") %>%
    stringr::str_replace_all("[[:cntrl:]]", " ")
```

I have also tried:

1. the step above also after downloading the files
2. `pdftools::pdf_attachments()` which gives me an empty list
3. as well as `pdftools::pdf_info()` also without success.

I could do it by hand but the corpus is quite large and so, before going in that direction, does anybody know how I could identify and extract embedded hyperlinks from PDF files using this package or anything else?

Many thanks!

Comment: @JeroenHeier, thanks for the tip! For sake of replicability, my preference would be to use a tool that can be called from R or from an R package. But if indeed no alternative exists, that seems very interesting.

Comment: @JM_Reis you can try to call command line from R and run the program from there. I couldn't find any documentation for command line operation though. Alternatively, you could look at PDFedit which seems to support command line operation and might be able to extract hyperlinks. http://pdfedit.cz/en/user_doc.html

Comment: @Gautam, will give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you can read the html links in a PDF if you read the PDF as a txt file. Hence, by reading the content of the PDF with the readr package, we can identify the html links using regular expressions. Here is an example :

````
library(readr)
library(stringr)
txt <- read_file_raw("C:/cp_47_17.pdf")
nb_Txt <- length(txt)
vector_Txt <- rep("", nb_Txt)

for(i in 1 : nb_Txt)
{
  print(i)
  vector_Txt[i] <- rawToChar(txt[i])
}

text <- paste0(vector_Txt, collapse = "")
position <- stringr::str_locate_all(text, pattern = "http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\\(\\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+")[[1]]
nb_Links <- nrow(position)
list_Link <- list()

for(i in 1 : nb_Links)
{
  list_Link[[i]] <- stringr::str_sub(text, start = position[i, 1], end = position[i, 2])
}
   
list_Link

[[1]]
[1] "http://www.corteidh.or.cr/)"

[[2]]
[1] "http://www.corteidh.or.cr/)"

[[3]]
[1] "http://www.corteidh.or.cr/docs/comunicados/cp_47_17.pdf)"

[[4]]
[1] "https://www.facebook.com/CorteIDH)"

[[5]]
[1] "http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/<?xpacket"

[[6]]
[1] "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns"

[[7]]
[1] "http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/"

[[8]]
[1] "http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef"

[[9]]
[1] "http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"

[[10]]
[1] "https://www.facebook.com/CorteIDH)"

[[11]]
[1] "https://twitter.com/"

[[12]]
[1] "http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/<?xpacket"

[[13]]
[1] "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns"

[[14]]
[1] "http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/"

[[15]]
[1] "http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef"

[[16]]
[1] "http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"

[[17]]
[1] "https://twitter.com/"

[[18]]
[1] "http://www.corteidh.or.cr/index.php/es/al-dia/servicios-de-informacion)"

[[19]]
[1] "http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/<?xpacket"

[[20]]
[1] "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns"

[[21]]
[1] "http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/"

[[22]]
[1] "http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceRef"

[[23]]
[1] "http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"

[[24]]
[1] "http://www.corteidh.or.cr/index.php/es/al-dia/servicios-de-informacion)"

[[25]]
[1] "http://www.corteidh.or.cr/)"

[[26]]
[1] "http://www.corteidh.or.cr/docs/casos/articulos/seriec_342_esp.pdf)"

[[27]]
[1] "http://www.corteidh.or.cr/docs/casos/articulos/resumen_342_esp.pdf)"

[[28]]
[1] "http://www.corteidh.or.cr/)"

[[29]]
[1] "http://www.corteidh.or.cr/)"

[[30]]
[1] "http://www.corteidh.or.cr/docs/comunicados/cp_47_17.pdf)"

[[31]]
[1] "https://www.facebook.com/CorteIDH)"

[[32]]
[1] "https://www.facebook.com/CorteIDH)"

[[33]]
[1] "https://twitter.com/"

[[34]]
[1] "https://twitter.com/"

[[35]]
[1] "http://www.corteidh.or.cr/index.php/es/al-dia/servicios-de-informacion)"

[[36]]
[1] "http://www.corteidh.or.cr/index.php/es/al-dia/servicios-de-informacion)"

[[37]]
[1] "http://www.corteidh.or.cr/)"

[[38]]
[1] "http://trk.masterbase.com/v2/MB/43BE8FF8FC213E8AFDF5C6C0803C9A652E6CDFC13A12FDC2E5C09FBFB97DD6E9408FA6607146839AE96FEDD9F5713F152BE58FE3CCB8B1668634E717A3978ED7C8EED4BD39E060B344A56FC3685757C06C9B126DBC220384CFC87FCCB2AF548AA356D747120AD53D6114AB4C4AE8EA30155DB2849E3238BE)"

[[39]]
[1] "http://trk.masterbase.com/v2/MB/43BE8FF8FC213E8AFDF5C6C0803C9A652E6CDFC13A12FDC2E5C09FBFB97DD6E9408FA6607146839A55FECA11A324ED5D48BA2676C114DAF357A5D3DADEDB8B263A674D6B08B83FA84DDF5A489225637078227BBFDF54AEB5CAEADE4351C689F3F5FA0D249DBC27A3C8EED4BD39E060B308BDAE9564459553)"

[[40]]
[1] "http://trk.masterbase.com/v2/MB/43BE8FF8FC213E8AFDF5C6C0803C9A652E6CDFC13A12FDC2E5C09FBFB97DD6E9408FA6607146839A71761C9609B8116B48BA2676C114DAF3654F31140F07355A7094CA8C3D18172C898EF5C0557D35B48D886CC77864DAA0085057CC9BBFCA5537B9BFF952BE91A54DDF5A48922563706577EAC6926D8A8D)"

[[41]]
[1] "http://trk.masterbase.com/v2/MB/43BE8FF8FC213E8AFDF5C6C0803C9A652E6CDFC13A12FDC2E5C09FBFB97DD6E9408FA6607146839A63BDE5C8E85A49EB2BE58FE3CCB8B1668634E717A3978ED7C8EED4BD39E060B3F29E78396CB7ADC526FC78E04ADA9C7425A0E5B485AC3EA0FB9CCF6F937BA723403C1985631A5441B387EB116B9F273ABFA1EF54FDDAEE0831C34ACAAEF604A80088D852DA56A988FAFF7F5C8E8523C8315FA93B1F341137)"

[[42]]
[1] "http://trk.masterbase.com/v2/MB/43BE8FF8FC213E8AFDF5C6C0803C9A652E6CDFC13A12FDC2E5C09FBFB97DD6E9408FA6607146839A13B26E68C26F9692C0FD35395A75F2386E73C2E55D0F1737EE6C58C832C8F9BA04A65C1BB9D0C9106D5EF8BD65DE6A546C9B126DBC220384CFC87FCCB2AF548AA356D747120AD53D6114AB4C4AE8EA30155DB2849E3238BE)"

[[43]]
[1] "http://trk.masterbase.com/v2/MB/43BE8FF8FC213E8AFDF5C6C0803C9A652E6CDFC13A12FDC2E5C09FBFB97DD6E9408FA6607146839A08B590D424E8B9296EE15DE3555B78744954C38A85CE5C46D2D441CD4016DC72B9F5A077A01802BB8D886CC77864DAA0085057CC9BBFCA5537B9BFF952BE91A54DDF5A48922563706577EAC6926D8A8D)"```
````